# Tomar el nombre de archivo y fecha de creacion con SSIS

Tags: ssis

estoy tratando de tomar el nombre del archivo(texto plano) y la fecha modificacion, y cargarlo en una columna extra con ssis, la carga es de varios archivos planos. Alguna idea, o ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ejecutar scripts de Windows como consulta de SQL con el comando xp_cmdshell.

Ej: EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir /T:W ruta archivo'

Y te devolverá la información básica del archivo buscado.